# Is it possible to execute DMV queries between certain time periods?

Tags: sql-server, ssas

We have a DMV query that executes every 10 mins and inserts usage statistics,  like `SESSION_CURRENT_DATABASE, SESSION_LAST_COMMAND_STARTTIME`, etc..  and supposedly has been running fine for the last 2 years.

Today we were notified by data hyperingestion team that the last records shown were from 6/10. So we found out the job has been stuck for 14 days not executing new statistics since. We've immediately restarted the job and it's been executing successfully since the morning, but basically we've lost the data during this 14 days period. Is there a way for us to execute this DMV query between 6/10-6/24 on the `$SYSTEM.DISCOVER` to recover these past 14 days of data?

Or all hope's lost?

DMV query:

```
SELECT [SESSION_ID]
      ,[SESSION_SPID]
      ,[SESSION_CONNECTION_ID]
      ,[SESSION_USER_NAME]
      ,[SESSION_CURRENT_DATABASE]
      ,[SESSION_USED_MEMORY]
      ,[SESSION_PROPERTIES]
      ,[SESSION_START_TIME]
      ,[SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME_MS]
      ,[SESSION_LAST_COMMAND_START_TIME]
      ,[SESSION_LAST_COMMAND_END_TIME]
      ,[SESSION_LAST_COMMAND_ELAPSED_TIME_MS]
      ,[SESSION_IDLE_TIME_MS]
      ,[SESSION_CPU_TIME_MS]
      ,[SESSION_LAST_COMMAND_CPU_TIME_MS]
      ,[SESSION_READS]
      ,[SESSION_WRITES]
      ,[SESSION_READ_KB]
      ,[SESSION_WRITE_KB]
      ,[SESSION_COMMAND_COUNT]
FROM $SYSTEM.DISCOVER_SESSIONS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say it's "gone" unless the instance has been restarted or the db has been detached. For example, the dmv for procedure usage should still have data in it, but you won't be able to specifically recreate what it looked like 10 days ago.

You can get a rough idea by looking back through the 2 years of data you already have, and get a sense of if there are spikes or consistent usage. Then, grab a snapshot of the DMV today, and extrapolate it back 14 days to get a rough idea of what usage was like.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you're saying we can ”predict” what the data looked like based on last 2 years of data we already have and basically insert records ourselves based on the ”extrapolation”/prediction?

Comment: That'd be my recommendation. You can also try to use a backup file from that time period, restore it, and see if the system level data is available. I don't believe it will be, though.

Comment: Gotcha. I was hoping itd be a little easier by simply specifying the timeframe or something...we dont have access to the prod sql server, so the only thing I can do I use SSMS to access the sql server instance and execute queries as I please. But in terms of a backup, i would have to ask a DBA to help us out. What exactly should I ask the DBA? Like is there a specific directory where these backups of the $SYSTEM.DISCOVER DMV data is backup in?

Comment: For example, lets say we're talking about either the index or procedure usage stats dmv. When you look at the data for the last 2 years, you see that the usage is fairly consistent with no spikes or valleys. Procedure A on 6/10 according to the DMV has been executed 10,000 times. On 6/24, Procedure A accordning to the DMV has been executed 17.000 times. This means its been executed 7,000 times in 14 days, so you can assume that the procedure is executed roughly 500 times a day.

Comment: Thanks for the scenario. unfortunately idk if executive management will consider relying on extrapolated data in this manner. besides that will probably complicate the recovery process and they may not be patient enough for us to analyze and extrapolate in time. oh well, i suppose lesson learned lol